# Is there a way to stop input() from escaping \n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, newline

So I'm trying to allow my user to input \n in a string, to designate a new line.
However for some reason that is translated into '\\n'. So I can do:

```
inp = input().replace("\\n", "\n")
```

but that seems a little cumbersome; is there a better way?

Comment: `input` is *not* escaping `\n`. There is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its representation. If you write `\n`, then you wrote a backslash and an `n`, not a new line. Input does *not* interprets the line (like the Python interpreter does)

Comment: `input().replace(r'\n', '\n')`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was under the impression that \n in a string leads to a new line being triggered when that string is printed & that the \n in e.g. "exam\nple" is just a string and nothing else.

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is the opposite of what you're asking for. You want to accept strings that are explicitly escaped by the user, and unescape them, right?

Comment: @Chaoscrasher, `len('foo\nbar')` is 7, not 8, because `\n` is just how Python writes out a single (newline) character; it *is not* a backslash followed by an `n` (if that's what it were, it would be written as `'foo\\nbar'`, with the backslash doubled to show that it's literal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for here is actually almost the opposite of what you're asking for.

`input` does not escape the string in any way; it returns exactly the string the user typed.

And, in fact, your attempted fix for that is, while probably not the best solution, fine.

---

I think your confusion is that you're mixing up the concept of string literals in source code with actual string values:

> I was under the impression that \n in a string leads to a new line being triggered when that string is printed & that the \n in e.g. "exam\nple" is just a string and nothing else.

No, `\n` in a string does *not* lead to a new line being triggered when the string is printed; only a newline character does that.

But `\n` in a string literal in your source code doesn't give you `\n` in the string, it gives you a newline character in the string.

When you write this:

```
>>> spam = "exam\nple"
```

… Python treats the `\n` as an escape sequence, and gives you a string value containing a newline character. So:

```
>>> print(spam)
exam
ple
```

The string doesn't have a backslash and an `n` in it, it has a newline in it. If you had a string that *did* have a backslash and an `n` in it, it would print that. For example:

```
>>> spam = r"exam\nple"
>>> print(spam)
exam\nple
>>> spam = "exam" + chr(92) + "nple"
>>> print(spam)
exam\nple
```

And that's exactly what's happening here: `input` is, again, giving you exactly the characters the user typed, including a backslash and an `n`.

You can confuse yourself even more by looking at the `repr` of a string, because the `repr` doesn't just show you the string, it shows you a string literal that you could feed into Python to get back the string:

```
>>> spam = "exam\nple"
>>> print(spam)
exam
ple
>>> spam
'exam\nple'
```

So, that explains why this works:

```
inp = input().replace("\\n", "\n")
```

It's not that the user's string has `\\n` in it, it's that the string literal `"\\n"` in your source is a backslash and an n, which matches what's in the user's input, while the string literal `"\n"` in your source is a newline, which is what you want to replace the backslash and n with.

---

What you're looking for is to allow the user to manually escape their input, in the same way you would do in a literal string in your source code, and then have your code apply those escape sequences, in the same way Python does to turn string literals in your source code into string values.

You can do that by manually processing escape sequences, like your code:

```
inp = input().replace("\\n", "\n")
```

But that's ugly if you want to handle other escapes. The simplest way to do that is to apply the `unicode-escape` codec, like this:

```
inp = codecs.decode(input(), "unicode-escape")
```

Now, if the user types `abc\ndef`, that will be unescaped into `abc`, a newline, and `def`.

Either way, if you want to do this many times, you can write a wrapper function:

```
def unescaped_input(prompt=""):
    return codecs.decode(input(prompt), "unicode-escape")
```

… and now:

```
inp = unescaped_input()
```

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining this to me and making it clear, instead of just taking a laugh, I really appreciate you taking the time :D; I wasn't aware \n actually is an ->escaped<- newline character; I thought \n ->was<- the newline 'character'.