# Why doesn't input( ) stops after encountering a newline?

Tags: python, input, newline

```
i = input('Enter : ')
print(i)
```

My input: `niraj\nraut<Enter>`

Output : `niraj\nraut`

Shouldn't the output be `niraj` if `input()` stops after encountering a newline character?

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248391/is-there-a-way-to-stop-input-from-escaping-n

Comment: Do you receive any result at all or any error messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to stop input() from escaping \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248391/is-there-a-way-to-stop-input-from-escaping-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work on python 2 and not on python 3.

Python 2 : 
input() parses escape characters, while raw_input() does not parse escape characters.

Python 3:
input() does not parse escape characters

In this case:

Python3's - input() = Python2's - raw_input()