# What is the difference between string literals and string values?

Tags: python, string, string-literals

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248681/13595466).

> I think your confusion is that you're mixing up the concept of string literals in source code with actual string values.

What is the difference between string literals and string values? I did not understand this.

Comment: A string literal is what you type into your source code. The string value is what gets output when you `print` it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A string literal is a piece of text you can write in your program's source code, beginning and ending with quotation marks, that tells Python to create a string with certain contents. It looks like

```
'asdf'
```

or

```
'''
multiline
content
'''
```

or

```
'the thing at the end of this one is a line break\n'
```

In a string literal (except for raw string literals), special sequences of characters known as *escape sequences* in the string literal are replaced with different characters in the actual string. For example, the escape sequence `\n` in a string literal is replaced with a line feed character in the actual string. Escape sequences begin with a backslash.

---

A string is a Python object representing a text value. It can be built from a string literal, or it could be read from a file, or it could originate from many other sources.

Backslashes in a string have no special meaning, and backslashes in most possible sources of strings have no special meaning either. For example, if you have a file with backslashes in it, looking like this:

```
asdf\n
```

and you do

```
with open('that_file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

the `\n` in the file will not be replaced by a line break. Backslashes are special in string literals, but not in most other contexts.

---

When you ask for the `repr` representation of a string, either by calling `repr` or by displaying the string interactively:

```
>>> some_string = "asdf"
>>> some_string
'asdf'
```

Python will build a new string whose contents are a string literal that would evaluate to the original string. In this example, `some_string` does not have `'` or `"` characters in it. The contents of the string are the four characters `asdf`, the characters displayed if you `print` the string:

```
>>> print(some_string)
asdf
```

However, the `repr` representation has `'` characters in it, because `'asdf'` is a string literal that would evaluate to the string. Note that `'asdf'` is not the same string literal as the `"asdf"` we originally used - many different string literals can evaluate to equal strings.

Comment: Nice answer!! So 'abcd' in the Python source code is a *string literal* and not a *string*, right?

Comment: @NSR: `'abcd'` is a string literal.

Comment: What does it mean by *It can be built from a string literal*?

Comment: @NSR: It means that one of the ways you might get a string is by having Python execute a string literal.

Comment: How to execute a string literal? - I am not sure of the words being used, probably, due to my poor English.

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: Strictly speaking python does **not** execute string literals, as a matter of English semantics. A string literal is a syntactic representation of a *specific* string as found in a text file. A string literal is **transformed** into a *value* by either the Python compiler or Python interpreter. The value of that transformed string, on the other hand, is the bit-for-bit representation of the string in memory at runtime.