# How can a string object be built from a string literal?

Tags: python, string, object, string-literals

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975501/13595466).

> A string is a Python object representing a text value. It can be built from a string literal, or it could be read from a file, or it could originate from many other sources.

I really did not understand, how can a string object be built from a string literal?

```
'''
multiline
content
'''
```

Also, how is the above a string literal? Please help me to understand the difference between string literals and string objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the python documentation on [Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals):

> Literals are notations for constant values of some built-in types.

A string literal is something that exists in source code - it's a way of writing the value of a string. A string object is the in-memory representation of a `str` object. You can compare this to an integer literal, like `5`:

```
x = 5  # x is assigned an integer value, using the literal `5`
y = x + x  # x is assigned a value
# Both are `int` objects
print(isinstance(x, int))  # True
print(isinstance(x, int))  # True

foo = "hello"  # foo is assigned a str value, using the literal `"hello"`
bar = foo.upper()   # bar is assigned a `str` value
# Both are `str` objects
print(isinstance(foo, str))  # True
print(isinstance(bar, str))  # True
```

You can do some [further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)), if desired:

> In computer science, a literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code.
>   ...
>   Literals are often used to initialize variables, ...