String Replace results differ from calling from a system command vs command line
We have a file that need ascii characters translated to another ascii characters for formatting purposes. We have always used perl -pe or sed to be called externally in a system command within a perl script to do this.
However since we moved to Red Hat from AIX, we have noticed that perl -pe doesn't work as expected from within the perl script then it does from the command line.
system("cat $AlifeFile | perl -p -e 's/\|.*MSH/\nMSH\|/g'| tr -d '\v'>> <outbound file name>");

Produces
MSH|
MSH|
MSH||
MSH|^
MSH|~
MSH|\
MSH|&
MSH||
MSH|A
MSH|-
MSH|L
MSH|i
MSH|f
MSH|e
MSH||
MSH||
MSH|I
MSH|D
MSH|X
MSH|_
MSH|T
MSH|E
MSH|S
MSH|_
MSH|C
MSH|H
MSH|G
MSH||
MSH||
MSH|2
MSH|0
MSH|2
MSH|4
MSH|0
MSH|5
MSH|0
MSH|9
MSH|1
MSH|3

if should be
MSH...
MSH...

when I am trying to replace \r034\r\v with a \n before the MSH segment in a HL7 message.
When I try that same system command but from a command line outside of the perl script it translates it correctly.
So why if I call it from the perl script inside a system command is it producing a different result then when I call that same code from a Red Hat Command Line?

What does the input file look like. If it has control characters, please describe where in detail.

Btw, if you are already running perl, why then do system() to pipe a file through some external commands? I'd stay in perl.

You are replacing a lot more with that substitution. This is a typical XY-problem. If you have weird line endings (never heard of that one before), reading a file in line-by-line mode might not even work, depending on what shell system decides to use. It might delete your whole file using the .* quantifier. According to perldoc unicode, \v can be written \p{VertSpace} as well. But you definitely have problems with quoting that you don't need to have.

Please show a sample of your input data

The Perl string literal
"… perl -p -e 's/\|.*MSH/\nMSH\|/g' …"

produces the string
… perl -p -e 's/|.*MSH/␊MSH|/g' …

Similarly,
"… tr -d '\v' …"

produces the string
… tr -d 'v' …

These aren't the shell commands you want to execute. Apply appropriate escaping.

Note that "\v" produces a warning. ALWAYS use use strict; use warnings; or equivalent.

Not sure what you mean by literal. The perl -p -e 's/|.*MSH/\nMSH/g' removes everything but the \v. From what my teammate is telling me is that Perl 5 does not recognize the \v.

yes, "... tr -d '\v' ..." also becomes ... tr -d 'v' ...

@sroth79 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)

@sroth79 perhaps also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975501/10971581

might it be slightly clearer to use > instead of backticks ? (I can never remember how to write them in comments)

Disagree ______

Re "Not sure what you mean by literal.", Text that is literally found in the program, i.e. source code.

I meant just for the result, not the input, in case that wasn't clear - the result is not more code, it is an actual string

@jhnc, 1) Actually, it is code. 2) Even if it wasn't code, that doesn't matter. 3) It's not a quote. Indicating it's one could be confusing and misleading. 4) Most importantly, different formatting would make the differences harder to spot. Consistency is key.

This is an unnecessary use of system and unnecessary use of cat. You can do all of this inside your Perl code with a few simple lines of code.
tr's \v is an escape representing U+0000B VT, so it can be written as \x0B and \N{VT} (among others) in Perl. Note that if your file's line endings are strange (\r034\r\x0B), which are not native to the current system, reading the file in line-by-line mode might slurp the file instead, and then .* might delete all your file content.
open my $fh, "<", $AlifeFile or die "Cannot open '$AlifeFile': $!";
open my $out, ">>", "outbound file" or die "Cannot open output file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    s/\|.*MSH/\nMSH\|/g;
    tr/\N{VT}//d;
    print $out $_;
}
close $fh;
close $out;


s/\p{VertSpace}//g; is removing all control characters including the hidden \n. How do I just remove the characters I specifically need to remove? Do I have to go through each of the ascii characters manually and substitute them?

@sroth79 Since I don't know much about what characters you need to remove, it's kind of hard to answer. Do you have a list?

Also, as near as I can tell, \v and \p{VertSpace} should be identical.

looks like it might be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7

His regex is looking for | before MSH though. That one is after.

Re "\v and \p{VertSpace} should be identical.", Perl regex's \v and Perl regex's \p{VertSpace} are identical. They match the same 7 characters. tr's \v, on the other hand, is VERY different. It's an escape that represents matches U+0B VT. I have fixed the code accordingly

Notes:

Sample data can be downloaded from here: https://confluence.hl7.org/display/OO/v2+Sample+Messages

The results are the same in Linux and Aix

You can debug it with truss -f (Aix) or strace -f -s4096 (Linux) and grep execve, eg:
execve("/usr/local/bin/perl", ["perl", "-p", "-e", "s/\\|.*MSH/\\nMSH\\|/g"], 0x18c7110)
execve("/usr/local/bin/perl", ["perl", "-p", "-e", "s/|.*MSH/\nMSH|/g"], 0xccd200)


The reason is the difference in string-escape between shell and perl: in shell, "\|" means two byte sequence 0x5c 0x7c; in Perl, it means single byte 0x7c.
On the other hand, '\|' in both context means the two byte sequence 0x5c 0x7c
Note: PHP and Python work like the shell.
